# Computing geodesic length of Euclidean lines in the manifold of positive definite matrices

Tags: riemannian-geometry, computational-complexity, na.numerical-analysis

I am working with the manifold of positive definite matrices $PD(n)$ equipped with the affine-invariant Riemannian metric (AIRM) $g_P(V,W):=tr(P^{-1}VP^{-1}W)$, where $P \in PD(n)$ and $V,W \in T_P PD(n) \cong Sym(n)$. Let $P \in PD(n)$ and $V \in Sym(n)$. Define $c(t)=P + tV$ for $t \in (a,b)$ where $a < 0 < b$ is the largest interval for which $c(.) \in PD(n)$. In my research, I have to compute the geodesic of $c$: $l(t) := L(c(0,t)) = \int_0^t \|V\|_{c(\tau)} d\tau$, where $\|V\|_P = \sqrt{tr(P^{-1}VP^{-1}V)}$ is the Riemannian norm from the AIRM. Now, I compute $l(t)$ using Riemann rectangles technique, but this is quite expensive. I was wondering if there is a closed-form expression, or a faster way to compute the length. Or alternative, a way to find a tight upper bound that is fast to compute.